# How can I filter by dates in a Firestore Realtime Database with pyhon?

Tags: python, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a firestore realtime database with the following structure:

[image]

And I need to be able to apply a filter for the dates. The idea is that the user enters a filter start date and a filter end date. I must deliver all the "alerts that are valid within that period of days".
In more practical terms, I need:

```
start_date <= end_filter,
final_date >= start_filter
```

I know I can't apply "multiple where clauses" (unfortunately), so my idea is to apply the first condition in the query (start_date <= end_filter) and then from my python code in the backend, apply the second condition (end_date >= start_filter).
Then, I tried the following:

```
def get_dates(self, path, params: FilterDates):
        return (
            self.db.reference(path)
            .order_by_child("start_date")
            .end_at(params.final_date)
            .get()
        )
```

But I got no results (I get an empty dictionary), what am I doing wrong?, I tried to guide me from the documentation but I don't know where I fail.